# why can't i change the setting of primative mesh objects in object mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh

When ever i try to change the setting of my mesh primitive in object mode, the panel with the configuration setting is visible, but i can't click on it. It seems that the only way i can get access to the configuration panel for primitive mesh objects is by going into edit mode for any mesh, deleting it, then adding a primitive object, which enable me to have access to the configuration panel for said mesh primitives.

problem:

[image]

(unpractical) Solution:

[image]

I really need an alternative. I wish to find a method or setting configuration that will allow me to have access to the primitive mesh setting as i add it in objects mode, and NOT have to go into edit mode, delete object, then add primitive(this is disruptive to  my workflow.)

all solution are considered, thank you!